# How to convert ByteBuffer to Bitmap Image?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am working on creating an image super-resolution application that uses a TensorFlow Lite model. The model gives the output Image in the form of ByteBuffer and I convert the ByteBuffer to Bitmap. Next, I display this Bitmap but nothing shows up. The code I am using can be seen below:

```
            ByteBuffer out = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * 384 * 384 * 3);
            tflite.run(byteBuffer,out);

            byte[] imageBytes= new byte[out.remaining()];
            out.get(imageBytes);
            final Bitmap outPut_Image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes,0,imageBytes.length);
            //Toast.makeText(this,tflite.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(outPut_Image);
```

Please advise me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(this, "Working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` ??? Working? You are checking nothing!

Comment: `if ( outPut_Image==null ) { toast bitmap would become too big for available memory and return}`.

Comment: Toast is just to check if try block is working or not.

Comment: Well ... Is the bitmap null? Why dont you react?

Comment: any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray() is used for compressed image data such as JPEG.

For raw RGB888 data, I think you should convert it to ARGB_8888 format first.
After that you can use the following snippet to create Bitmap object.

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
```